# Saxonica Generate SEF file from xslt and apply the same for transformation

Tags: xslt, saxon

I am trying to find/know the correct approach to save sef in memory and use the same for transformation

Found below two approaches to generate sef file:

**1. using xsltpackage.save(File)** : it works fine but here need to save content to a File which doesn't suit **our requirement as we need store in memory/db**.

**2. XsltExecutable.export()**  : it generated file but if i use the same .sef file for transformation, i am getting empty content as output(result).

I use xsl:include and document in xslt and i resolved them using URI resolver.

I am using below logic to generate and transform.

**Note**:  i am using  **Saxon ee (trial version)**.

**1.XsltExecutable.export()**

```
 public static String getCompiledXslt(String xsl, Map<String, String> formatterMap) throws SaxonApiException, IOException {     
        
        try(ByteArrayOutputStream destination = new ByteArrayOutputStream()){
        Processor processor = new Processor(true);
        XsltCompiler compiler = processor.newXsltCompiler();
        compiler.setURIResolver(new CigURIResolver(formatterMap));
        XsltExecutable stylesheet = compiler.compile(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xsl)));
        
        
        stylesheet.export(destination);
        return destination.toString();
        }catch(RuntimeException ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

**use the same SEF for transformation:**

```
    Processor processor = new Processor(true);
    XsltCompiler compiler = processor.newXsltCompiler();
    if (formatterMap != null) {
        compiler.setURIResolver(new CigURIResolver(formatterMap));
    }
    
    
    XsltExecutable stylesheet = compiler.compile(new StreamSource(new StringReader(standardXsl)));
    Serializer out = processor.newSerializer(new File("out4.xml"));
    out.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.METHOD, "xml");
    out.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.INDENT, "yes");
     
    Xslt30Transformer trans = stylesheet.load30();
    if (formatterMap != null) {
    trans.setURIResolver(new CigURIResolver(formatterMap));
    }
    
    trans.transform(new StreamSource(new StringReader(sourceXMl)), out);

    System.out.println("Output written to out.xml");

}
```

when use the sef generated from above export method to transform , i am getting empty content..same code works fine with sef generated from XsltPackage.save().

**UPDATE** : *solved the issue* by setting false to property (by default it is true) compiler.setJustInTimeCompilation(**false**);

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are looking for, both your title and your first introduction talk about "generate SEF file from xslt" but then the sentence "need to save content to a File which doesn't suit our requirement as we need store in memory/db" suggests a file on the file system is what you *don't* want.

Comment: thanks, updated the question -> "save sef in memory and use the same for transformation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's very little point (in fact, I would say there is no point) in saving a SEF file in memory. It's much better to keep and reuse the `XsltExecutable` or `XsltPackage` object rather than exporting it to a SEF structure and then reimporting it. The only reason for doing an export/import is if the exporter and importer don't share memory.

You can do it, however: I think the only thing you need to change is that you need to close the destination stream after writing to it. Saxon tries to stick to the policy "Anyone who creates a stream is responsible for closing it"

Comment: thank Micheal, manually closing the stream solved the problem (was thinking it is auto closable), regarding storing the object instead of sef file, we are planning to persist/keep them in redis cache and multiple threads/instances will access them... thank you will try out option.

Comment: looks like net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltExecutable is Not Serializable, will have to go with XML format

Comment: UPDATE : solved the issue by setting false to property (by default it is true) compiler.setJustInTimeCompilation(false);

not sure if it has do with xslt content.

Comment: Interesting, I would have expected that doing an export() would trigger the necessary eager compilation, or at least give a clear error message...